# Prime ng Calendar year range changes when clicking arrows to year outside of range

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I have a p-calendar element that is working correctly, but it has an annoying ui bug that allows the user to click to a year outside of the yearRange. They cannot selected a day in a year outside of the yearRange, as expected, but when they click on the year dropdown from a date outside of the yearRange, the yearRange in the dropdown is different. (e.g. if the original yearRange is 2016:2022 and the user selects Dec 2022 then clicks arrow to Jan 2023, when they click the year drop down they will now see 2022-2028)

```
      <p-calendar 
                name="arrivedate" 
                [showIcon]="true" 
                [monthNavigator]="true" 
                [yearNavigator]="true" 
                yearRange="2016:2022" 
                formControlName="arrivedateCtrl" 
                dateFormat="yy/mm/dd" 
                placeholder="{{requireText}}" 
                readonlyInput="readonlyInput" 
                [locale]="calLanObj">
      </p-calendar>
```

I'm trying to find a way to either not allow the user to click the arrows to a year outside the yearRange, or that when they click the year dropdown from a date outside of the range they will see the original yearRange in the dropdown.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no *intended* way to do this. So your options are:

1. Make a request to the devs in the github issues: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues
2. Grab the source code from the github and modify it to what you want - you might even be able to merge it into the main product since primeng is open source: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/components/calendar
3. Use this **janky** hack:

We'll add event listeners for `onYearChange` and `onMonthChange`. Also, a template id so we can use `ViewChild` to do some questionable stuff.

```html
<p-calendar
  #calendar
  [(ngModel)]="date"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [minDate]="minDate"
  [maxDate]="maxDate"
  (onYearChange)="checkYear($event)"
  (onMonthChange)="checkYear($event)"
>
</p-calendar>
```

I've removed the deprecated property `yearRange` and use `minDate` and `maxDate` instead.

Then we'll add a function to check the year is within our bounds when the user changes it. We'll use `@ViewChild` to access all the functions and variables that we're *not supposed to*. Through trial and error, I found that calling the `onModelTouched()` function and then resetting our date value will update the date in the calendar.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('calendar') calendar?: Calendar;
  minDate = new Date(1451624400000); //Jan 1 2016
  maxDate = new Date(1672462800000); //Dec 31 2022
  date = new Date();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  checkYear(date: { month: number; year: number }) {
    if (this.calendar) {
      if (date.year < 2016) {
        this.calendar.onModelTouched();
        this.date = new Date(this.minDate);
      }
      if (date.year > 2022) {
        this.calendar.onModelTouched();
        this.date = new Date(this.maxDate);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the user picks a date not within our range, we set it to the minimum or maximum value. We need to make sure to set the date using `new Date()` to ensure change detection will trigger every time.

Keep in mind this is using the component in an unintentional way, so there's no guarantee it won't break in future versions.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-emw3ge?file=src/app/test/test.component.ts